# ggplot2 - setting breaks regardless of the range of y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to set breaks on my y-axis so that they appear after every 10 units. Usually you would use something like:

```
p+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 10))
```

However, what if I'm using a dataset that's updating every day and the maximum level of the y-axis changes very often? I'd like to find a workaround so that the breaks appear every 10 units regardless of what the maximum value of the scale is. I want to avoid having to change `100` inside the `seq` function to some other number every few days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify `breaks` as a function of the data. This should work:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(z) seq(0, range(z)[2], by = 10))
```

(I use `z` here to illustrate that it's an anonymous function for which the name of the argument doesn't matter.)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Is there maybe a way to use `~` instead of specifying it like in your answer?

I tried the following two variants but they didn't work:

`scale_y_continuous(breaks = ~seq(0, range(z)[2], by = 10))`

`scale_y_continuous(breaks = ~seq(0, range()[2], by = 10))`

Comment: I don't use `purrr` a whole lot, so I can't really help with that. I think maybe you need to make the argument `.x` to use purrr's anonymous functions? But even then, I'm pretty sure the `~` syntax only works inside functions that have been specially built for it, as `purrr` and certain `dplyr` functions have.